# How do I launch my own configuration without overriding .NET Core's built-in configuration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, configuration

I've created a launchSettings.json file in Visual Studio 2022, enabling me to quickly change configurations such as the database connection string from Visual Studio's launch settings dropdown.

**LaunchSettings.json**

```
"iisSettings": {

    "iisExpress": {

      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost",

      "sslPort": 44392

    }

  },

  "profiles": {

    “Client_1”: {

      "commandName": "IISExpress",

      "launchBrowser": true,

      "environmentVariables": {

        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": “Client_1_ENV

      }

    },

    “Client_2: {

      "commandName": "Project",

      "launchBrowser": true,

      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",

      "environmentVariables": {

        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Client_2_ENV"

      }

    }

  }

}
```

**appsettings.client_1_ENV.json**

```
{
   “ConnectionStrings”: “db.client_1.com”
   "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
```

**appsettings.client_2_ENV.json**

```
{

   “ConnectionStrings”: “db.client_2.com”
   "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
}
```

Since **launchsettings.json** uses **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** as a key for selecting the associated appsettings, I can't use .NET Core's built-in configuration such as **RELEASE**, **STAGING**, and **DEVELOPMENT**. Consequently, my code as well as its dependencies can't respond to the built-in configuration.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to configure `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"` in `appsettings.client_1_ENV.json`/`appsettings.client_2_ENV.json`

They would be all overrided by that  in launchsettings.json accroding to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environment-variables-set-in-generated-launchsettingsjson), and your enviromentname would be `Client_1_ENV`/`Client_2_ENV`

You could try add the jsonfile mannully as below for debug(Note the section share the same name would be overrided):

launchsettings.json:

```
"profiles": {
    "Client_1": {
      ......
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development.Client_1"
      }
    },
    "Client_2": {
      ......
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development.Client_2"
      }
    },
```

In Program.cs:

```
var env = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;
var realenv = env.Split('.')[0];
var filename = String.Format("appsettings.{0}.json", realenv);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(filename);
var targetstr = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySection").Value;
var connectstr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConStr");
builder.Environment.EnvironmentName = realenv;
```

in appsettings.Development.json:

```
"MySection": "Sction1"
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is precisely what I considered, but I figured there had to an easier way. Unfortunately, the decision to use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as a key for selecting the appsetting configuration was a poor choice since it elides the built-in comfiguration. The documentation states you can use any value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT without mentioning the consequences. It seems Microsoft doesn't think through some of its decisions.